# content of the div not aligning to center

Tags: html, css

I have created a UI that contains two sections. The section on the left displays a table of values and the section on the right displays a pie chart. I am unable to get the content of the pie chart to the center of its div. As you can see information on the left is slightly chipping. I have temporarily given solid borders to the `divs` to understand the layout. I tried several options but it didn't work.

Code

```
<div class="form-group row">

  <div style="border:solid" class="panel panel-default col-md-12">

    <div style="border:solid;float: left; margin-top:0px ;height: 100%" *ngIf="AllocationDetails && AllocationDetails.MissingProducts"
      class="alert alert-danger col-md-5">
      <p><strong>The investments made in the following products are not included in this report:</strong></p>
      <table>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let group of AllocationDetails.MissingProducts">
          <tr>
            <th> {{group[0].ProductType}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let post of group">
            <td> {{ post.ProductName  }} </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="spacing"></td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div style="border:solid;display:inline-block;" *ngIf="AllocationDetails && AllocationDetails.ChartData" class="col-md-7">
      <app-pie-chart style="margin-left:40px;"  [series]="allocation_series"></app-pie-chart>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You appear to just have `margin-left: 40px` on your pie chart. Don't you want `margin: 0 auto`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular but  `app-pie-chart` is a component,right?

Comment: yes its a component. margin:0 or margin: auto doesnt work

Comment: the app-pie-chart renders a div in the DOM ?

Comment: if the chart is made to render below the pink section then it shows completely

Comment: try `display: block` and `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: where on the piechart or its parent div

Comment: app-pie-chart renders a div on the dom

Comment: I applied on pie chart display: block and margin: 0 auto  and it didnt work

Comment: I think this depends largely on the chart output code. The chipping on the left doesn't seem to be caused by your code.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: There could be some code in the rendered chart that causes the alignment problem.

Comment: Two common ways of centering horizontally: 1) Block-element: Margin: auto on both sides + requires set width. 2) Inline- / inline-block elements: By setting text-align: center on the containing element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried add this **align="center"** in the Div tag

example

```
<div align="center"> content </div>
```

If that doesn't work try adding margin-left:"20%"

```
<div margin-left:"20%"> content </div>
```

using percentages allows it to scale the margin depending on the size of your display

Comment: I'm afraid that is a mix of deprecated and incorrect code.

Comment: I tried this and it didnt help.Both the sections render correctly on big screen. But when i try to resize the browser, the second section starts to get hidden by the first section

Comment: Difficult to help without seing this more completely, with pie chart included.